# FTP using bash script with Grunt Task Manager

Tags: node.js, bash, ftp, gruntjs, grunt-exec

I am trying to FTP files from local distribution build to production using Grunt. I have tested by bash file and it works. I just can't get it to run using grunt.

In my grunt file:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig( {
        ...
        exec: {
            ftpupload: {
                command: 'ftp.sh'
            }
        }
    } );

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
    grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['ftpupload']);
};
```

I try `grunt deploy` at the command line and get the following error:

```
Warning: Task "ftpupload" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

I try `grunt exec` at the command line and get the following error:

```
Running "exec:ftpupload" (exec) task
>> /bin/sh: ftp.sh: command not found
>> Exited with code: 127.
>> Error executing child process: Error: Process exited with code 127.
Warning: Task "exec:ftpupload" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

The `ftp.sh` file resides in the same directory as `Gruntfile.js`.

How can I configure it so that I can run `grunt deploy` and have the bash script run?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options to try....

#### Option 1

Assuming that [grunt-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec) allows a shell script to be run (*...it's not a package I've used before*!) reconfigure the `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig( {

        exec: {
            ftpupload: {
                command: './ftp.sh' // 1. prefix the command with ./
            }
        }
    } );

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

    // 2. Note the use of the colon notation exec:ftpupload
    grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['exec:ftpupload']);
};
```

**Note**

1. The change to the `exec.ftpupload.command` - it now includes a `./` path prefix, as you mention:

   > `ftp.sh` file resides in the same directory as Gruntfile.js.
2. The alias Task List in the registered `deploy` Task now utilizes the semicolon notation, i.e. `exec:ftpupload`

---

#### Option 2

If Option 1 fails for whatever reason use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) instead of *grunt-exec*.

1. Uninstall *grunt-exec* by running: `$ npm un -D grunt-exec`
2. Install *grunt-shell* by running: `$ npm i -D grunt-shell`
3. *grunt-shell* utilizes a package named [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks), so you'll need to install that too by running: `$ npm i -D load-grunt-tasks`
4. Configure your `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig( {

        shell: {
            ftpupload: {
                command: './ftp.sh'
            }
        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['shell:ftpupload']);
};
```